# Why is my laptop losing so much power while in suspend mode?

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management

Last time I used my laptop, I had it plugged in, and so at the time I closed the lid and put it into suspend mode, it had 100% power. However, when I opened the lid now, the a day later, and resumed work, the power is down to 40%.

I've noticed before the laptop losing power while in suspend mode, but so far it's always been in the range of 5~10%, so I thought that was a lot, but I assumed it might be a normal amount of power drain.

I understand that suspend mode does use a small amount of power to keep the memory in RAM, but clearly a drop from 100% to 40% in 24 hours indicates a problem.

I already have the TLP power management system installed.

Why is my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop losing so much power during suspend mode?

Comment: is it a thinkpad?

Comment: @Rinzwind, no, it's an Asus Zenbook.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu is not very power efficient, so, installing any third-party software will solve your problem. The best third-party software as such available is TLP.

To install TLP install:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install tlp`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I alreasy have TLP installed, though. I should have mentioned that in my question, so I'll update it.