# My laptop (HP) loses all the battery power while it is suspended

Tags: suspend, power-management, hp

I recently got a HP laptop with 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5 and I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I suspend it, in few hours it loses all the battery power so I have to recharge it again.
[I have tried installing the tlp utility with no luck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700278/why-is-my-laptop-losing-so-much-power-while-in-suspend-mode).

Comment: Are you sure it suspends? Does it matter howw do you suspends, close the lid or click on the menu?

Comment: It looks like: screen turns off and after pressing a key the computer wakes up and I have to write the password. But it's true that the laptop stays hot. Maybe some key is touched and it wakes up? How could I disable the keyboard so I wake up only using the power button?

Comment: Use the commands [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8112/how-do-i-detect-when-the-system-suspends/1103944#1103944) and then copy and paste the output from the terminal into your question. Format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Looking at the logs, it seems that closing the lid make the computer to wake up :S I will investigate further. Thank you @user68186.